# Disputed flag: typo problem

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-flags

I may have misunderstood this, so I would like clarification.

I flagged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821879/the-method-lenght-is-undefined-for-the-type-string as off-topic for the following reason:

> Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or that
>   was caused by a simple typographical error**. While similar questions
>   may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to
>   help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and
>   closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the
>   problem before posting.

However, my flag was disputed. Did I use this flag incorrectly?

Comment: No, the flag was correct. I'm not quite sure why it got disputed.

Comment: Your flag was correct. In fact, the question has already been closed by others for exactly that reason. I'm not sure why your flag would have been disputed.

Comment: Disputed flag means that some non-community-moderator user disagrees with the flag, usually due to some (robo) reviewer decides to leave this question open.

Comment: There was probably a horse shoe that disagreed and decided that the question was worth answering.  There is one obvious candidate shoe, he got two upvotes for his answer.  Seems he was right.

Comment: @HansPassant ah, the one who's up to 7?

Comment: It looks like your flag was disputed in the triage [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10272543)

Comment: @HansPassant I am not familiar with the phrase "horse shoe". Could you elaborate?

Comment: [Jon Skeet](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eHNtxAH2crk/UAOGcMs7LOI/AAAAAAAAAHM/B1UfNLfaz-s/s320/fancy-shoe.jpg), [most users](http://www.jadesignershoes.com/image/cache/data/Webreadyfinished/BrownFancyMensShoe-375x375.jpg), [that user](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Used_horseshoe_%28inside%29_J3.jpg/766px-Used_horseshoe_%28inside%29_J3.jpg)

Comment: @NathanOliver As far I know, that is triage, while the flag push it to the close queue, through if it had two flags (vlq and close) and triage handled it maybe we are seeing a bug, where the competition of a review task affects all flags on the post.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's a reasonable and correct flag, particularly because of:

> or that was caused by a simple typographical error

Which is all this question is about. Your flag should have been accepted. I'm not sure what the reviewers thought when disputing this.

Side note: The question is now properly on hold, as it should be.